# Not equal to function is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Not equal to function is not working in below code when I am running it through Postman, but the same query is giving output in MySQL.
Laravel Eloquent Code -

```
Invoice::where('invoices.centre_code', $userInfo->centre_code)
                    ->where("invoices.itemTotalPrice","<>", "invoices.paymentCollected") // this line is not working
                    ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_code', '=', 'invoices.customerCode')
                    ->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'invoices.itemId')
                    ->select('invoices.*', 'customers.customerName', 'customers.customerDialCode', 'customers.customerCity', 'customers.customerAddress', 'customers.customerMobile', 'items.itemName')
                    ->whereBetween('invoices.created_at', [$from, $to])
                    ->oldest("invoices.nextPaymentDate")
                    ->get();
```

Above code returning this SQL query, and when I ran it MySQL cmd it working perfectly.

```
select `invoices`.*, `customers`.`customerName`, `customers`.`customerDialCode`, `customers`.`customerCity`, `customers`.`customerAddress`, `customers`.`customerMobile`, `items`.`itemName` from `invoices` inner join `customers` on `customers`.`customer_code` = `invoices`.`customerCode` inner join `items` on `items`.`id` = `invoices`.`itemId` where `invoices`.`centre_code` = 705405 and `invoices`.`itemTotalPrice` <> invoices.paymentCollected and `invoices`.`created_at` between 2023-03-24 00:00:00 and 2023-03-24 23:59:59 order by `invoices`.`nextPaymentDate` asc
```

Exactly this code is not working `->where("invoices.itemTotalPrice","<>", "invoices.paymentCollected")`

We are expecting the data where **invoices.itemTotalPrice** != **invoices.paymentCollected**, but whenever we ran the code it fetching all data within the given date. If **invoices.itemTotalPrice** == **invoices.paymentCollected** it should exclude those rows, but this is not working. We are using Laravel 10.0

Comment: Can you paste the dump from `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())`?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi  [] // app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController.php:118
Returning a blank array

Comment: Above the `Invoice::where` add `\DB::enableQueryLog();` and then after the `Invoice::where()->...get();` add `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi  [Error Log](https://truemi.in/log0.jpg)

Comment: You should paste the log here. As text. Anyways, the `itemTotalPrice` is being printed with `=` instead of `<>`.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If you run the generated query manually in MySQL, does it yield the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `->whereColumn ('invoices.itemTotalPrice', '<>', 'invoices.paymentCollected')` to compare columns

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the log you had pasted in a comment, we can see `<>` being treated as `=`

To simplify the problem you could use:

```
->whereNot("invoices.itemTotalPrice", "invoices.paymentCollected")
```

Answer (score 0):

The where eloquent helper accepts either an array of a series of arguments.

The series of arguments can be either

1. Column | value (this will equate to `column=value`
2. Column | operator | value (this will equate to `column<operator>value`

So in your given eloquent code your `invoices.paymentCollected` is being evaluated as a value

If you need to place constraints on joins please use the syntax described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses)

Or you can use self joins if the columns are part of the same table

Or you can use the `whereColumn` syntax as mentioned by [@Pippo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75833135/2757519)

Comment: If you try ```User::whereColumn ('updated_at', '<>', 'created_at')``` in tinker, you can see that is returned *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder*